# Depth of object and depth perception

Tags: graphics

What is the relationship between the depth of the target 3D object that you wish to draw perception on, and the perceptive depth that is visible.

E.g. if I know a square is x by y by z and I wish to draw it in perspective at distance d hwo do I know how long the z (depth) line should be drawn in relation to the vanishing point (should I draw it 2/3's of the way or 1/5th of the way).

Is there a relation between the two, like; multiply the depth by `DepthObject / distanceToVanishingPoint` = perceptiveDepth.

THanks.

Answer (score 2):

With perspective projection, your view frustum appears like a triangle from a top (x, z) view. You have a [nice theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem) which explains the relation between sides of triangles and parallel lines.

For a more practical solution, you should have a closer look at [projection matrices](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html).